# Log process output to file RobotFramework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to capture the results of my logging to do a diff in the end and verify the results are what as expected on Robot test. I've tried adding the following:
`stdout=/path/to/file` however that only seems to print python 'print()' statements and doesn't actually utilize my loggers. I was wondering, if I do the following:

```
Test Case
   Start Process   python  ../Scripts/test.py
```

How do I get the logs produced by test.py in a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

You can always run the proces in shell and just redirect output of the command. Like so

```
Process.Start Process    python3 ../Scripts/test.py > ../Scripts/test.log    shell=yes    alias=test
```

I would also suggest to use [${CURDIR}](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#built-in-variables). That way you can execute your robot from different locations and it will still work.

Comment: I didn't think of this. Thank you Jiri, I will give this a try.